# Клиент принимает больше байт чем на сервере

Tags: c++, windows, ftp, winsock, client

При передаче данных с фтп-сервера на компьютер, система принимает больше байт чем нужно. Работаю с *winSock*, пишу свой клиент. 
Принимаю данные от сервера обычным способом через *recv*. К примеру, файл на сервере весит 5400 байт, а когда я его принял, он стал весить 5502 байта, допустим.

Чем это обусловлено, не подскажете? И есть ли способ как это решить?

```
    while ((no_of_bytes = recv(c2->getSock(), text, 256, 0)) > 0)
    {
        text[no_of_bytes] = '\0';
        cout << text;
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос - а там не принимается ли `\n`, которое потом в файл вы записываете как `\r\n`?... Конечно, в духе "у вас не работает компьютер? А включен ли он в розетку?", но не задать не могу...

Comment: Да, есть такое.

Comment: Да посмотрите просто, чем отличается исходный файл от полученного, без всяких отладчиков!

Comment: ничем не отличается. просто весит больше и всё. но я так понял это из-за  `\r\n`

Comment: Простите, но это же смешно - "ничем не отличается, но размер больше" :) Значит, отличается? Посмотрите в любом вьювере с 16-ричным представлением - в том же Far в конце концов...

Comment: ну я же сказал, что отличается тем, что `\r\n` добавляется. при чем сумма `\r`'ов если сложить с суммой байт исходного файла будет равна результирующей сумме байт полученного файла

Comment: Ну вот и решение. Вы получаете все верно, добавляете лишнее в `cout << text`. Записывайте файл в бинарном режиме, и все будет отлично :)

Comment: Ну так я понимаю, что вопрос закрыт. И закрыт благодаря усилиям Harry. Предлагаю Harry оформить свой комментарий ввиде ответа, а Идентикон, так как получил правильный ответ, отметит этот ответ как решение. Или есть возражения? :)

Comment: Благодарю. Но есть замечание/вопрос: если я буду считывать обычный текстовый файл в бинарном режиме, то мы же его потом не сможем посмотреть как обычный.

Comment: Нет, почему же? При считывании текстового в бинарном режиме просто не будет преобразования `\r\n` в `\n`, так что проблем не будет.

Comment: Отлично. Но тогда надо дать знать серверу, что я буду принимать данные в бинарном режиме, верно? Командой `TYPE I`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Считывание в `recv` выполняется в бинарном режиме, а запись `cout << text` - в текстовом, что приводит к тому, что считанный `\n` превращается в `\r\n`.

Запись файла в бинарном режиме должна решить данную проблему.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло. Принимается всё верно 100% из 100% байт, не больше и не меньше. Но как быть с записью. Когда мы приняли данные от сервера, там как и должно быть, хранятся переносы строк `\n`, и вот при записи в файл в текстовом режиме уже на компьютере размер файла увеличивается на кол-во `\n`. Может подскажете как быть с этим?

Comment: Например, записывайте его в файл с помоью потока `ofstream`, открытого в режиме `ios::binary`.

Comment: Записывал так, но `\n` пропадают и всё выходит в одну строку.

Comment: Пропадают или просто конкретный вьювер настолько глупый, что не показывает разделение строк по `\n`? Все отличие текстового режима от бинарного в том, что при чтении он не превращает `\r\n` в `\n`, а при записи - `\n` в `\r\n`, т.е. работает с данными в файле "как есть".

Comment: ну вот я считываю 256 байт в массив. Там присутствуют `\n`. Размер считанных байт сервера одинаковый. т.е. считывает всё нормально. Но когда я записываю в файл в текстовом режиме, то размер файла увеличивается относительно кол-ва `\n`. т.е.  как вы и сказали `при записи - \n в \r\n`. Вот меня и интересует вопрос, как избавиться от лишних байт?

Comment: ofstream of("file",ios::binary); of.write(buf,size);

Comment: это не работает. решил проблему путем записи в бинарном режиме с помощью функций языка СИ.

Comment: Это работает. Видимо, вы не тот size передаете или еще что... Впрочем, это уже слишком далекор зашло от начальной темы...